# Android - How to change file to view with SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to work this function but I can't. My application hasn't got a SQL database, it has only .xml files. I would like to change file to view by the preferences settings, for example I would be able to view or the file data.xml or the file data2.xml checking or unchecking a checkbox.

Activity PreferencesFromXml:

```
public class PreferencesFromXml extends PreferenceActivity{

    public static final String COLORE_DEFAULT = "#000000";

    public static final String COLORE_PREF = "colore";

    public static final String TITOLO_PREF = "titolo";

    public static final String USA_TITOLO_CUSTOM_PREF = "usa_titolo_custom";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

            SharedPreferences prefs =     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

            Preference titoloPrefs = findPreference(TITOLO_PREF);
            titoloPrefs.setSummary(prefs.getString(TITOLO_PREF, getString(R.string.titolo_custom)));
            titoloPrefs.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener()
            {
                    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference prefs, Object value)
                    {
                            prefs.setSummary((CharSequence) value);
                            return true;
                    }
            });
    }
}
```

Main Activity:

```
public class Main extends ExpandableListActivity{
    ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Group> groups;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.list_main);

            groups = readGroupsFromXml();

            mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(getLayoutInflater(), groups);
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);
            registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());
    }

    public ArrayList<Group> readGroupsFromXml()
    {
            try
            {
                    final XmlHandler handler = new XmlHandler();
                    final SAXParser sp = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
                    sp.parse(getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data), handler);
                    return handler.getGroups();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                    Log.e("Error", "xml", e);
            }
            return null;
    }
```

Then I don't know what to do to choose the file to use when the checkbox is selected or not. I stopped here (although I don't know if it's correct):

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    String usa_titolo_custom;
            if (prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesFromXml.USA_TITOLO_CUSTOM_PREF, false))
            {
```

As you can see from the code .xml files are located in res/raw. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set up a boolean shared prefs and use it. Put these as global variables ...

```
SharedPreferences data;
public static String filename = "filename";
boolean b;
```

Then in `onCreate()` put

```
data = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
```

set the boolean with

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
editor.putBoolean("data", b);
editor.commit();
```

get the boolean like this, where `default` is true or false, depending on what you want it to be **if** it's not set.

```
 b = data.getBoolean("data", default);
```

then use something like

```
public ArrayList<Group> readGroupsFromXml() {

b = data.getBoolean("data", false);
if (b == true){ 
    try {
        final XmlHandler handler = new XmlHandler();
        final SAXParser sp = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
        sp.parse(getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data), handler);
        return handler.getGroups();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", "xml", e);
    } 
} else {
    try {
        final XmlHandler handler = new XmlHandler();
        final SAXParser sp = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
        sp.parse(getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data2), handler);
        return handler.getGroups();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", "xml", e);
        }
    }
return null;

}
```

If `b` is true it uses data.xml, if it's false it uses data2.xml.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately I didn't understand in which activity put the code. `public ArrayList<Group> readGroupsFromXml() {` etc. I know that goes in Main Activity but the rest? I didn't understand what I need to write in the other Activity. The checkbox is `public static final String USA_TITOLO_CUSTOM_PREF = "usa_titolo_custom";`.
 Sorry to bother you.